# Android GridView first item background is not working

Tags: android, android-gridview

I want to set custom background of gridview but when grid load, first item of grid background is not load and remaining all item load properly.
Below is my code so please help.

```
    public class PicassoExample extends Activity {

    private GridView gvFirst;
    private ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList;
    private PicassoImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picasso_example);

        gvFirst = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvFirst);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<MyModel>();

        loadArraylist();

        adapter = new PicassoImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
        gvFirst.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void loadArraylist() {
        arrayList.add(new MyModel("http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg"));
        arrayList.add(new MyModel("http://i.imgur.com/C9pBVt7.jpg"));
        arrayList.add(new MyModel("http://i.imgur.com/rT5vXE1.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Here is my Adapter class.

```
    public class PicassoImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList;

    public PicassoImageAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList) {
        context = applicationContext;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    class Holder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myView = null;
        try {
            Holder holder;
            myView = convertView;

            if (myView == null) {

                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_picasso, null);
                holder = new Holder();

                // here I am setting custom backgroud of each item of gride.
                myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corner_gride_layout);

                holder.imageView = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                myView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (Holder) myView.getTag();
            }

            MyModel model = arrayList.get(position);
            Picasso.with(this.context)
                    .load(model.getStrUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myView;
    }
}
```

here is xml for adapter.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

actually I have used `Picasso` library to load photo from internet. I have created custom background for each item of gridview but when gridview load first then only first item (zero position of grid) of grid not working and all item of gridview's background set properly.

Comment: write code of set background of color of view out side the if else condition.
myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corner_gride_layout);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using below code.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View myView = null;
    try {
        Holder holder;
        myView = convertView;

        if (myView == null) {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_picasso, null);
            holder = new Holder();

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            myView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (Holder) myView.getTag();
        }
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>15)
        {
            myView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.corner_gride_layout));
        }
        else {
            myView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corner_gride_layout));
        }

        MyModel model = arrayList.get(position);

        Picasso.with(this.context)
                .load(model.getStrUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .into(holder.imageView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: Could you mention in your answer, how is this the solution for your problem?

Comment: Hi Jayesh I have use  `myView.setBackground` in my code.

Comment: @SakibSyed I am using below code on button click 
private Button[] tempBtn = null; 
tempBtn[position] = btnView;
on click>>
 for (int i = 0; i < tempBtn.length; i++) {//set alpha to 0.5 for all buttons
                    tempBtn[i].setAlpha(0.3f);
                }
but it's updating aplha for all button except first one so what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of parent view is zero when you first invoke getView method.Maybe you can obtain screen content width and height to set their values.
add these line of code after myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_picasso, null);

```
myView.setLayoutParams(new  
AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   
AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return convertView when it is not null in getView().

```
if(convertView != null){
    return convertView
}
*Here is what you want to let view do*
```